# How to make dir tree from array

Tags: php

I haw got a array of directory's that i wont to use for the directory tree with this code below... My question is how to make a tree from this array? With this code I get this:

```
Array (
    [0] => store/555555//Osnovni documenti
    [1] => store/555555//Ostali dokumenti
    [2] => store/555555//Pictures )
```

NOW how to inplement this ?sou I can get the directory tree ? Is ther something that can do that?

```
echo"<pre>";

function make_tree_recursive($path, $levels){
//where $path is your source dir, $levels is the maximum recursives
    $handle=opendir($path);
    while($a=readdir($handle)){
      if(!preg_match('/^\./',$a)){
        $full_path="$path/$a";
        $list[]=$full_path;

        if((is_dir($full_path))&&(!preg_match('/(\/.+){'.$levels.',}/',$full_path))){
          $recursive=make_tree_recursive($full_path, $levels);
          for($n=0; $n<count($recursive); $n++){
              $list[]=$recursive[$n];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    closedir($handle);
    return $list;
}

$list = make_tree_recursive("store/".$diro."/", 3);
print_r ($list);
echo"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flip path array using array_flip and use the library explodeTree

```
// let '/' be our delimiter
$tree = explodeTree($key_files, "/");
// show the array
print_r($tree);
```

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/convert_anything_to_tree_structures_in_php/

Comment: if(exec("find /etc/php5", $files)){
    // the $files array now holds the path as it's values,
    // but we also want the paths as keys:
    $key_files = array_combine(array_values($files), array_values($files));
 
    // show the array
    print_r($key_files);
}

Comment: But it have't outputed nothing I don't no why

Comment: in if("find /store/555555, $files") and ect.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat <<000 >a0.a
aa/store
aa/store/555555
aa/store/555555/Osnovni documenti
aa/store/555555/Ostali dokumenti
aa/store/555555/Pictures
000

cat a0.a |
    grep -P . |
    while read d0; do echo --- $d0; mkdir -pv $PWD/aa/"$d0"
        done
```